# Does anyone know how to translate this single line of Java code into Python?

Tags: java, python, user-interface, backend

So basically I just need help translating this single line of Java code for my Python project.

`C_ID.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(C_ID.getText())+1));`

It's part of this entire syntax;

```
private void Save_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    if (C_Name.getText().length() == 0 || C_Email.getText().length() == 0 || C_Add.getText().length() == 0 || C_Contact.getText().length() == 0 || C_Birth.getText().length() == 0) {    
        messageBox("Customer Input Fields Cannot Be Incomplete", "Record");
    }
    
    else if(check_minor == false){
        messageBox("Customer cannot be a minor.", "Record");
    }
    
    else if (check_email == false){
        messageBox("Please input a valid E-Mail address", "Record");
    }
    
    else if (check_dateValid == false){
        messageBox("Please input a valid date", "Record");
    }
    
    else{
        messageBox("Save Record?", "Record");
        C_ID.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(C_ID.getText())+1));
    }
    }
```

So what this does is every time I press the save button, the Input Field will increment by 1.

Is there a way to translate that from Java to Python?

Comment: You incorrectly copied part of your code.

Comment: You mixed parenthesis. In your longer example you have `C_ID.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(C_ID.getText())+1));` but at start of your question you are asking about `C_ID.setText(String.valueOf().Integer.parseInt(C_ID.getText())+1));` which probably won't even compile.

Comment: My bad! I'll edit it again so there's no confusion! Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `C_ID` functions are the same, all you need are the equivalent of integer casting and stringifying an int.

- `Integer.parseInt()` is the same as `int()` in Python.
- `String.valueOf()` is the same as `str()` in Python.

It's that simple.

Comment: Would "C_ID.setText" be the same as C_ID.configure(text="")?

Comment: @LeandroTupas `C_ID` is a custom class, right? Then you have to reimplement it in Python, or find its equivalence to use. As of what you have given, I don't know what exactly is `C_ID`.

Comment: `C_ID` is an entry field/input field that's supposed to be disabled.

Comment: @LeandroTupas that still doesn't help me know what interface `C_ID` is defined with, or its equivalent in Python. What entry field? From HTML? How are you getting HTML input with Python? Flask/Django? That needs a lot more information.